# named fifo error - C programming

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo

I'm trying to write and read from a named fifo with some methods... Apparently when I run it gets stuck on write_fifo(0) for no reason... So my question is am I using named fifo in the right way? Or does the unlink method mess with my program? When and where can I unlink a named fifo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)


void write_fifo(int s)
{
    printf("write_fifo");
    int writing, n;
    writing = open("myFIFO",O_WRONLY);
    n = write(writing, &s, sizeof(s));
    printf("write: %i byte.\n", n);
    close(writing);
    unlink("myFIFO");
}

int read_fifo()
{
    printf("read_fifo");

    int reading, n, s;
    reading = open("myFIFO", O_RDONLY);
    n = read(reading , &s, sizeof(s));
    printf("read: %i byte: %d\n", n, s);

    close(reading);
    unlink("myFIFO");

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("beginning");

    printf("removing myFIFO");

    if (mkfifo("myFIFO", FILE_MODE) == -1) 
    {
        perror("myFIFO");
        exit(1);
    }

    write_fifo(0);

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\nReading %d",read_fifo());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man mkfifo`: *[...]However,  it  has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.[...]*

Comment: To avoid blocking on `open(2)` of a writer, when the reader process is not running, you might want to use a nonblocking `open(2)` call, _e.g._: `writing = open("MyFIFO", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);`. You might also add checking for errors from your `open(2)` system calls.

Comment: I've used the O_NONBLOCK option and now it runs but it doesn't write and read anything and the write function returns -1.  And what does it mean I have to open both ends simultaneously? Did you mean in the open function I've to give it both permissions read and write?

Comment: Is there any option to both read and write?

Comment: Okay I've solved my issue. I've used O_RDWR to both write and read. Even if I don't know why I can close() in the read_fifo and not in the write_fifo. If you submit your answer I can give you a thumbs up. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can write your own answer, and accept it if is right.